# Sending verification email with Meteor causing error

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have the following:

```
Template.joinTemplate.events({
"submit #Signup-Form": function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var email = template.find('#Email').value;
    Accounts.createUser({
        username: template.find('#Email').value,
        emails: {
            address: template.find('#Email').value
        },
        password: template.find('#Password').value,
        profile: {
            firstname: template.find("#Firstname").value,
            lastname: template.find("#Lastname").value

        }
    }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            // Deal with errors
        } else {
            Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(this.userId, email);
            Router.go('/');

        }
    });
}
});
```

But get the following error:

```
 Error logging in with token: Error: You've been logged out by the server. Please login again. [403] debug.js:41
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'createUser': TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sendVerificationEmail'
    at http://localhost:3000/client/views/application/authentication/join_template.js?0ca175e5dc0f3b4596ed33e260d5636f8f9cc69b:28:26
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:801:19
    at loggedInAndDataReadyCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/accounts-base.js?efdcc57c69f7e2ccbb61f1e963da216b1729ac72:455:5)
    at null._callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?2b578107b8239ff9bc64200e6af2a24001461b30:801:22)
    at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?418d88f2513ae6bf0ff1447759a5c590923456bd:3502:12)
    at _.extend.receiveResult (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?418d88f2513ae6bf0ff1447759a5c590923456bd:3522:10)
    at _.extend._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?418d88f2513ae6bf0ff1447759a5c590923456bd:4452:9)
    at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?418d88f2513ae6bf0ff1447759a5c590923456bd:3376:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?418d88f2513ae6bf0ff1447759a5c590923456bd:2705:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

I have all accounts-base, accounts-ui, accounts-password installed.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_sendverificationemail), `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail` is only available on the server, and you're trying to use it on the client.

I'm not sure that you can use the `Accounts.onCreateUser` function to send verification emails: in this function, the user has not been added to the `Meteor.users` collection yet, and I guess `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail` requires the user to be in that collection. I don't know the best way to solve this, but you can always use a cursor selecting all users, and then observe users added to the collection (although, this is not a good solution).

It's not enough to use the `sendVerificationEmail` field in the [Accounts.config](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config) function?

Comment: Thank you Peppe. I missed the obvious. Would you mind explaining how I pass the newly created userId to the sendVerificationEmail? For example, if I put "Meteor.call('VerifyEmail', _Id? <-- in my success function in above example? I'm using the OnCreateUser as well now, but not understanding how to get the proper userID sent to the email function. Thanks again :)